# Google reverse geocoding no more available?

Tags: rest, api, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I'm getting this error when I perform a google maps reverse geocoding call (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.7061609,10.5948236&key=$MY_API_KEY):

```
{
  "error_message" : "This API project was not found. This API project may have been deleted.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Just to be clear: this worked until today.

Are the API changed? Do you know a workaround/fix?

Comment: No, it is working. Error message indicates that your API key is not valid anymore.

Comment: Then, the error_message is misleading: how do you know it regards the API key?

Comment: _This API project was not found_ : You create your API key inside a project on [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

My script tracks the movable marker on the map and displays the nearest Google address, both as lat/lng and nearest full_location when the drag stops. Had the same error message (in the browser Development error message). Resolved the creation of an new API key and the script that I have now works fine PROVIDED THE SCRIPT IS RUN DIRECTLY IN A BROWSER --- BUT as soon as I run the EXACT SAME SCRIPT using an -a- tag from HTML in my PHP application the lat/lng is resolved but the corresponding nearest address now comes up with the error message -Cannot determine address at this location.- from the script.
I cannot figure out what I have to change in the code to get it to work in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The API has not changed it seems. I had the same issue,
Go to Google API Console 
Search for Geocoding API 
Enable this for the credential and it worked for me